# Error when i try to send a Json from my app

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to send a json from my Flutter app to my Flask Backend app, but the json is not being sent.

My Dart Code:

```
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = {
      "Title": "Titulo da todo",
      "Description": "Descrição da todo",
    };

    final response = await client.post("http://10.0.2.2:5000/todo", body: jsonEncode(jsonMap);

    final Map result = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(result);
  }
```

the result.body is always {'error' : 'invalid'}

Python code

```
def create_todo():
    try:
        json = request.get_json()
        print("Json: ", json)
        #return {'ok' : 'ok post'}
        return jsonify(TodoService().create(json))
    except:
        return {'error' : 'invalid'}
```

```
Json:  None
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2019 16:27:00] "POST /todo HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Maybe the error is thrown at this line: `return jsonify(TodoService().create(json))`

Comment: Wokds fine when i make a request using python

import requests
requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/todo", 
                  json={"Title":"Titulo da todo", 
                        "Description":"Descrição da todo"
                        "DueDate Date('2019-12-01')"})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [flask documentation](https://kite.com/python/docs/flask.request.get_json):

> By default this function will only load the json data if the mimetype
>   is application/json but this can be overridden by the force parameter.

Make sure you add the content-type header:

```
  await client.post(
    'http://10.0.2.2:5000/todo',
    headers: {'content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'},
    body: utf8.encode(json.encode(jsonMap)),
  );
```